# Audience Manager exception when looking up a contact

Tags: web8, audience-manager

When trying to find a Contact, we are using the following code:

```
var contact = Contact.FromIdentificationKeys(identifiers);
```

The specified identifiers are an `identification-ID` (f0bdc058-a8b9-4567-bd4d-d9a8dc450101) and a `Identification-source` (Femcare_FR).

There is no contact yet with this details, but that should be fine and normally results in a `ContactDoesNotExistException`. In another environment this works fine, but it throws the following exception in the problematic environment.

> Timestamp: 21/09/2017 10:24:50 Message: System.Exception: Error connecting to Audience Manager: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"Retrieving Contact failed for internalId: null, emailQueryString: null, identificationKeys: [\u0022f0bdc058-a8b9-4567-bd4d-d9a8dc450101\u0022,\u0022Femcare_FR\u0022]"}}

It seems a misconfiguration of AM, because the exact same code works on another environment. Only I have no idea what could be wrong. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I think it would help if you **edit** your question and add some details about your question, like what are you exactly doing to get this error? You mention  the code works on another environment, so you could add a snippet of the code you are executing to your question for example.

Comment: Check the log file in the Audience Manager service. Right after this "Retrieving Contact failed for internalId..." error will be the exception that is the cause of the problem.